# How we set to ng-model variable to parent controller in nested controllers scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have one ng-controller nested in another controllers scope.
I want to set scope variable in nested controller scope, to parent controller. 
I have view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    <div ng-controller="CountryDataController">
        <angucomplete
        (...)
        selectedObject="country"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

which is part of the form. 
Then on form submit i want to send ng-models from **MyCtrl** ( name,country) doing:

```
fields: {name: $scope.name, 
        country: $scope.country,
        },
```

How can i tell angular, that selectedObject model belongs to MyCtrl, and not CountryDataController. 
I tried

```
selectedObject="MyCtrl.country"
selectedObject="country[MyCtrl]"
```

but without effects.

selectedObject in angucomplete works like ng-model. 
Also I don't want to rewrite logic from CountryDataController to MyCtrl, because in first i have fields for autocomplete and in second file uploading.

Is there any convention for this?

Comment: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/nestedcontrollers/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
selectedobject="$parent.country"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$parent`, but if you move your HTML or eventually add another controller it between it will break.

The correct way to do that is to use the `controller as` syntax, as shown below:

```
<!-- use topCtrl to access this controller scope -->
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as topCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
  <!-- use countryCtrl to access this controller scope -->
  <div ng-controller="CountryDataController as countryCtrl">
      <angucomplete
      (...)
      selectedObject="topCtrl.country"/>
  </div>
</div>
```