# ng-click with angularjs set scope

Tags: angularjs

I implemented `ng-click` using AngularJS but it seems not working, I'd like to send to my view the selected customer in the `ng-repeat`...

My code :

```js
var app = angular.module("GestiawebApp", []);

app.controller("CustomerController", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/eccustomer').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.customers = data;
  });
  $scope.chooseCustomer = function(customer){
    $scope.choosingCustomer = customer;
  };
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" ng-model="searchCustomer" required placeholder="Prénom ou nom du client" autocomplete="off">
<ul ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:searchCustomer | limitTo:5">
  <li>{{customer.firstname}} <a href="#" ng-click="chooseCustomer(customer)">Choisir</a></li>
</ul>
<p>{{choosingCustomer.firstname}}</p>
```

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: No nothing... the `ng-repeat` works fine and I'm able to get `costumer` in the `chooseCustomer` function...

Comment: ok do you have `firstname` property in `customer` ?

Comment: Yes I vahe `firstname` in `customer` ;) but I found the issue, the scope was sending in another controller ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
ng-click="$parent.chooseCustomer(customer)"
```

Because inside the ng-repeat your scope changes

Comment: It doesn't work too, but I was thinking about the controllers, my `<p>` is inside another controller, that's not the same controller, how to pass the customer into the other controller?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618337/how-we-set-to-ng-model-variable-to-parent-controller-in-nested-controllers-scope